# Using a for-loop, in another for-loop, to iterate through a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'd like to write a set of for-loops that iterate through a list of lists as shown below.

```
pathways = ['pathway_1','pathway_2']

pathway_1 = ['gene_A', 'gene_B']
pathway_2 = ['gene_C', 'gene_D']

for i in pathways:
    for ii in i:
          print(ii)
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
gene_A
gene_B
gene_C
gene_D
```

but currently generates this:

```
p
a
t
h
w
a
y
_
1
p
a
t
h
w
a
y
_
2
```

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the outside loop you are looping over a string and not a list, change the code like this:

```
pathway_1 = ['gene_A', 'gene_B']
pathway_2 = ['gene_C', 'gene_D']

pathways = [pathway_1, pathway_2]

for i in pathways:
    for ii in i:
          print(ii)
```